# which ANSI characters does isblank detect ?

Tags: c

As the topic says - for what characters would `isblank(int c)` return true ?

Haven't found any entry about that function here on SO.

Comment: You can test yourself, loop from zero to 255 and try `isspace` on all. Or you check a manual page [like this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y13z34da%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) or [like this](http://linux.die.net/man/3/isspace).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you've set the current locale to something other than `"C"`, it will only return true for `' '` and `'\t`'.

[N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> #### 7.4.1.3 The `isblank` function
>
> ...
> 2 The `isblank` function tests for any character that is a standard blank character or is one
> of a locale-speciﬁc set of characters for which `isspace` is true and that is used to
> separate words within a line of text. The standard blank characters are the following:
> space (`' '`), and horizontal tab (`'\t'`). In the `"C"` locale, `isblank` returns true only
> for the standard blank characters.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from the manpage:

> isblank()
>   checks for a blank character; that is, a space or a tab.

http://linux.die.net/man/3/isblank

if you want to check for all whitespaces, use `isspace()`.

Comment: Btw, that man page contradicts itself and applies specifically to GNU/Linux rather than to C in general.

Answer (score 1):

It's locale-specific.

In the "C" locale, *only* space and horizontal tab are blanks. In other locales there may be additional blanks, all of which necessarily are also spaces according to `isspace`.

This is in the definition of `isblank` in the C standard, by the way. There's nothing in principle wrong with having one or more SO questions per paragraph of the standard, but there's also no need to ask them all just to populate the site ;-)

Comment: Making matters worse, ANSI isn't well-defined either in this context.  What Windows refers to as "ANSI" will *also* depend on the locale.